# Sitecore - Require login

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

So for my Sitecore site I am trying to make it so the user is logged in and can not use the extranet\Annoymous account.  I have read and tried

[Implementing Sitecore Extranet login on a website](http://www.bolaky.net/post/Implementing-Sitecore-Extranet-login-on-a-website.aspx)

But I missed something, the asp forms authentication has side issues that it returns you to the original page and thus ignoring the user's option of Desktop or Page Editor.

The part where I am frustrated is that it seems this logic is already built into SiteCore.  For example if I try to go to http://site/sitecore/shell and I am not logged in site core redirects me to the login page.  So how can I turn this on for my entire site.

**UPDATE**

My Security Editor looks like this 
[image]
[image]

Even if I unprotect the sitecore object and deny access to the main object 
I can still get to the site.
[image]

In the web.config my Sites section looks like this

```
<sites>
  <site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Base" enableWorkflow="true" enableAnalytics="false" analyticsDefinitions="content" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="International" htmlCacheSize="2MB" registryCacheSize="3MB" viewStateCacheSize="200KB" xslCacheSize="5MB" disableBrowserCaching="true" />
  <site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableAnalytics="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true" />
  <site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx" />
  <site name="service" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service" />
  <site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
  <site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" />
  <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/Base" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" loginPage="/sitecore/login/Default.aspx" />
  <site name="scheduler" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" cacheMedia="false" />
  <site name="system" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" />
  <site name="publisher" domain="sitecore" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
</sites>
```

I know who I am logged in as because I added this to my homepage

```
<asp:Label ID="Id" runat="server"><%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to add

```
requireLogin="true"
```

to the site "website" tag

```
<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/Base" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" requireLogin="true" loginPage="/sitecore/login/Default.aspx" />
```

Comment: I will add to this that after you deny Read Permission to say Home item for extranet\Anonymous user. You need to publish master database to web to get this working.

Answer (score 3):

In Sitecore Security Editor, deny read access to Home item for extranet\Anonymous and grant access to your specific user/role. Also specify the Login page in Web.config for users to be redirected when authenticated session does not exists.

Comment: Sounds that easy but that does not seem to be working I am adding more detail to the question to make sure I understood you correctly